# Some definitions related to real form of Lie group

Tags: definition, lie-groups

I'm looking for a few definitions. I understand that $W$ is a real form of a complex Lie group $G$ if the complexification of $W$ is $G$.

> I want to know what it means to say **"let $\sigma$ be the complex conjugation of $G$ wrt real form $W$"**?

From where I'm reading, it says **"recall that Cartan involution is an automorphism $C$ of $W$ such that $C^2 = 1$ and such that $\tau = \sigma C = C \sigma$ is the complex conjugation wrt some compact real form $U$ of $G$."**

> I would like some elaboration on the above paragraph. For example what is this $U$ exactly?